# ui-gmap-window with directives and expressions

Tags: angularjs, google-maps-api-3, angular-google-maps

I'm trying to put some HTML template in `ui-gmap-window`.
The HTML contains directives such as `ng-click` and `ng-repeat` but they do not work.

```
<ui-gmap-google-map bounds="map.bounds" 
                        center="map.center" 
                        zoom="map.zoom" 
                        options="options">
      <ui-gmap-window options="windowOpt"
                      show="windowOpt.show"
                      closeClick="closeWindow">
        <div class='map-popup'>
            <div><a ng-click='doIt()' href='#'>Action</a></div>
            <div ng-repeat="item in list">
                {{item.content}}
            </div>
        </div>
      </ui-gmap-window>
</ui-gmap-google-map>
```

Or maybe I need to use another way to create something like carousel inside of a `ui-gmap-window`?

Thanks

Here is a sample:
http://plnkr.co/edit/k8vvW3

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Googled around slightly, found [this Github issue](https://github.com/angular-ui/angular-google-maps/issues/823).

To put it shortly, to use ng-repeat (or other angular directives) inside your window, you'll need to pass an external window template and custom template parameters to your `<ui-gmap-window>` as follows:

index.html:

```
<ui-gmap-window options="windowOpt"
    show="windowOpt.show"
    closeClick="closeWindow"
    templateUrl="'windowContent.html'"
    templateParameter="windowParams">
</ui-gmap-window>
```

script.js:

```
$scope.windowParams = {
    list: $scope.list,
    doIt: function() {
        return $scope.doIt()
    }
}
```

windowContent.html:

```
<div class='map-popup'>
    <div><a ng-click='parameter.doIt()' href='#'>Action</a></div>
    <div ng-repeat="item in parameter.list">
        {{item.content}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Plunker to demonstrate: http://plnkr.co/edit/mu8jfCJhwSHbCghYpdkr?p=preview